# Launching msconfig.exe on 64-bit Windows

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit

I have a form with the code:

```
private void msconfigButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msconfig.exe"); 
}
```

The idea is I click a button and it starts msconfig for me. Problem is when I run it on a x64 machine it crashes with a `Win32Excpetion` was unhandled error saying it can not find the file. I know the file exists in C:\Windows\System32\ and I believe this is related to my project being compiled for a `x86` CPU type.

How can I rewrite the code so that it starts msconfig.exe on a 64 bit computer? I do not want to change the CPU type for building it. The idea is that I can run this program on either a 32 or 64 bit Window 7 machine and it works just the same.

Comment: Use "sysnative" instead of system32.

Comment: Great suggestion, Hans! I've never used that before, but I used it like you said and it worked perfectly! Simple and quick, thank you!

Comment: @TonyCampbell can you add your answer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way to avoid this issue is by changing the build type. See 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/csharplanguage/thread/ad97bb81-0566-4eb9-b1e1-c591476a4958
If anything it seems that maybe looking into the File System Redirector could provide some insight or a workaround!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, Twiltie. I did consider changing the build type, but when I did that it broke the registry redirector I am using in other parts of the project. So, I'm thinking it might be easier to fix this than it is to adjust the other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

One way around this would be to write a simple x64 application that started msconfig.

Your application then stays as x86 and your Process.Start would start your wrapper application, which would in turn start msconfig.

For example, create a new console app (lets call it 'msconfigstarter') with the following:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\windows\\system32\\msconfig.exe");
    }
}
```

Set it's build platform to x64.

Now you can add that exe ('msconfigstarter.exe') to your application project as a content file that gets copied to your output folder, or include it in your installer as an output file.

Then change your button click code to:

```
private void msconfigButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msconfigstarter.exe"); 
}
```

This works around the problem that the file system redirector swaps the System32 folder for x86 apps because you start an x64 app that you do know exists 'msconfigstarter.exe' which can then access msconfig.exe because the system32 folder is not redirected for it.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, Matt, I'm still learning, lol! So, from what you are saying, would it be possible to design another application to start msconfig, compile/build it for x64 CPUs, then tell my current application to start that instead of msconfig directly? Would it then be possible to intigrate both programs into one, maybe using a MSI installer or something similar?

Comment: Tony, I've edited my answer to go into a bit more detail, hope it helps!

Comment: That is awesome, Matt! I'll see what I can do with this, thank you for the input and details!

Comment: I tried a suggestion from Hans and switched 'system32' to 'sysnative' and it worked. While it was quicker then creating a new app, you gave me some great ideas on how to proceed with other parts of my program with additional executables. Much appreciated!